# how to log body with ogma nestjs-module

Tags: logging, nestjs, ogma

I just setup ogma nestjs-module using this [doc](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/tree/main/packages/nestjs-module)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    OgmaModule.forRoot({
      service: {
        color: true,
        json: false,
        application: 'NestJS'
      },
      interceptor: {
        http: ExpressParser,
        ws: false,
        gql: false,
        rpc: false
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: OgmaInterceptor
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

set it global

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { logger: false });
  const logger = app.get<OgmaService>(OgmaService);
  app.useLogger(logger);
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

It works, but I wonder how to log request and response body as currently it does not log that info.

Comment: Where in the log do you want to add the body? Depending on where in the log, I may need to add new functionality to the interceptor parsers

Comment: Just want to be able to print the json in the log, as right now using `morgan-body` for that. Right after the post, as it is something you want to be able to turn off easily on prod. So I guess similar to `morgan-body`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Do you want the body to be inline with the rest of the request log, or is it something you'd want to have on a separate line? If inline, where in the line? That's what I'm looking to know

Comment: Yeah to have it as a separate line would make more sense then have it as a part of request info. Also it would be great to be able to prettify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like what you're looking for you can probably do the following

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomOgmaInterceptor extends OgmaInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    return super.intercept(context, next).pipe(tap(() => {
      this.service.log(context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body);
    }));
  }
}
```

And now you can bind the custom interceptor like

```js
{
  provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
  useClass: CustomOgmaInterceptor,
}
```

And that should be all there is to it.

---

As I'm the author of the package, I may end up adding in a `getMeta()` or `getExtra()` method to the request parsers so that this can be handled automatically via extending the parser rather than extending the interceptor

---

## Edit 9/7/2021

`@ogma/nestjs-module@3.1.0` is now available and this is possible to implement without extending the interceptor. Simple extend an existing parser and override the `getMeta` method like so:

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExpressParser } from '@ogma/platform-express';

@Injectable()
export class CustomExpressParser extends ExpressParser {
  getMeta(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const body = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;

    return Object.keys(body).length ? body : 'no body';
  }
}
```

This will result in the interceptor making two logs, one for the usual data, and one for the extra metadata. [You can read more in the docs here](https://jmcdo29.github.io/ogma/)

[image]